# If $A,B$ are square matrices of the same order, given, $A^4=I,A^2=B^2,AB=BA^3$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, show $A^3B=BA$ and $A^2B=BA^2$.

Tags: matrices

The question is:

$A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same order.

Given that,  $A^4=I,  A^2=B^2,   AB=BA^3$,  where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Show that $A^3B=BA$  and  $A^2B=BA^2$.

My workings:

1). For showing $A^3B=BA$

Using $AB=BA^3$,  multiplying on right By$A$ $\implies  ABA=BA^4$

$\therefore  ABA=B$,  since $A^4=I$

Multiplying on left by $A^3  \implies A^3ABA=A^3B$

$\therefore  A^4BA=A^3B  \implies BA=A^3B$

$\therefore A^3B=BA$ ... Result!

2). For showing $A^2B=BA^2$

$A^2B=A(AB)$,  and $A(AB)=A(BA^3)$,  from given $AB=BA^3$,

and, $A(BA^3)=A(BA)A^2$

$\therefore  A^2B=A(BA)A^2 ... (1)$

From the given $AB=BA^3$,  multiplying on the right by $A$ gives,

$ABA=BA^4 \implies ABA=B$, since $A^4=I$

$\therefore (1)$ becomes,

$A^2B=BA^2$ ... Result!

Comment: You could prove this using group theory; presentations, in particular.

Answer (score 3):

The second equation is much easier to prove:
$A^2B=B^2B=BB^2=BA^2$.

For the first one, notice that since $A^4=I$, $A$ is invertible. $AA^3B=A^4B=IB=BA^3A=ABA$, left multiplied by $A^{-1}$, we got $A^3B=BA$.

Comment: Thanks for positive input, and another insight!

Answer (score 1):

According to GAP, the group given by

$$P:=\langle A,B\mid A^4=I,  A^2=B^2,   AB=BA^3\rangle$$

is the quaternion group $Q_8$:

```
gap> F:=FreeGroup(2);
<free group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> rels:=[ (F.1)^4, (F.1)^2*(F.2)^(-2), (F.1)*(F.2)*(F.1)^(-3)*(F.2)^(-1) ];
[ f1^4, f1^2*f2^-2, f1*f2*f1^-3*f2^-1 ]
gap> G:=F/rels;
<fp group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> Size(G);
8
gap> StructureDescription(G);
"Q8"
```

Furthermore, it can be computed using GAP whether those identities hold:

```
gap> (G.1)^3*(G.2)=(G.2)*(G.1);
true
gap> (G.1)^2*(G.2)=(G.2)*(G.1)^2;
true
```

This can be seen more directly by mapping $A\mapsto i$ and $B\mapsto j$ in the quaternions.

Comment: I know! You could always upvote it to compensate, @user1176409 ;)

Comment: Yeah I couldn't understand the downvote! I'm only wanting to contribute POSITIVELY to this site, not end up feeling disheartened by a NEGATIVE experience!